# Reduce run time - Clojure

Tags: clojure, sequence

If I have less than 100 tags I can use this, which runs sequentially. If I have hundreds of thousands of tags, it is very time consuming.

Should be able to run to delete tags more than 100 000 which can run in parallel and also add some logs

Comment: Please use universal measurements and avoid using local words like *lakh* which the rest of the world does not use or understand

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: I suggest looking at claypoole: https://github.com/clj-commons/claypoole

Comment: Note that [codereview.se] is generally a better place for questions that aren't about a narrow, specific technical problem with a piece of code.

Comment: (also, Clojure has a fair number of concurrency primitives included in the standard library -- promises and agents among them, in addition to the ability to directly use Java's pools and such; any of the textbooks on the language will cover all of these with advantages and disadvantages of each).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [the Claypoole library](https://github.com/clj-commons/claypoole).  Sample code:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [com.climate.claypoole :as pool]
    ))

(defn task [] (Thread/sleep 10))

(defn slow
  []
  (newline) (prn :slow)
  (doseq [i (range 100)]
    (task)))

(defn fast
  []
  (newline) (prn :fast)
  (pool/pdoseq 8 [i (range 100)]
    (task)))

(verify
  (time (slow))
  (time (fast)))
```

with results:

```
time (clojure -X:test)

Running tests in #{"test"}

Testing tst._bootstrap

------------------------------------------
   Clojure 1.12.0-alpha3    Java 20.0.1
------------------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core

:slow
"Elapsed time: 1012.908212 msecs"

:fast
"Elapsed time: 137.932203 msecs"

Ran 2 tests containing 0 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
  36.50s user 0.85s system 284% cpu 13.150 total
```

So we see an 8x speedup by using 1 thread on each cpu core (i.e. the `8` after `pdoseq`).  For I/O dominated workloads, you could benefit by using many more threads (eg 64).

Built using [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).